# C Parsing functions not working

Tags: c, parsing, pointers, char

I'm trying to write a program that will be used for demonstration on
 some basic parsing, but C isn't my main language.  There's a problem with this the way it is, and i'm trying to get it to print this output.

output:
FOO/4200, FOO, 4200

it's suppose to show the combination, then each separate.

```
char *afterSeparator(char *complete)
{
    char *separator = strchr(complete, '/');
    if(slash) 
    {
    return separator + 1;
    }
    return complete;
}

char *beforeSeparator(char *complete)
{
    char *separator = strchr(complete, '/');
    if(separator)
    {
        *separator = '\0';
    }
    return complete;
void printParts(void)
{
    char original[] = "FOO/4200";
    char *preSeparator = beforeSeparator(original);
    char *postSeparator = afterSeparator(original);
    printf("%s, %s, %s\n", original, preSeparator, postSeparator);
}
```

Comment: You overwrite the `'/'` and then search for it...

Answer (score 1):

When you use "beforeSeparator" you overwrite the '/' with '\0'. This will terminate the string in the middle.
When you spawn "afterSeparator" you do not have the '/' in the string any more.

Answer (score 1):

Call `afterSeparator` before after you call `beforeSeparator`.

In all your order should be

1. First print original
2. Call afterSeparator
3. Call beforeSeparator
4. Print preSeparator & postSeparator

`beforeSeparator` replaces the `/` with a `\0`. Hence calling `afterSeparator` after calling `beforeSeparator` will not work. Also printing `original` after calling `beforeSeparator` will not give the right results because it will print only `FOO` because of the `\0`.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a sample for you.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
char str[100] = "Hello/Jay";

printf("\n%s\n", strrchr(str, '/')+1);
str[strlen(str)-strlen(strchr(str, '/'))] = '\0';
printf("\n%s\n", str);

return 0;
}
```

Modify it according to your needs.